# ykman installation

Tags: 18.04, python3, python-2.7

I tried installing ykman in ubuntu-18.04(WSL) using below commands,

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:yubico/stable
sudo apt update
sudo apt install yubikey-manager
```

when I try to find the version using: `ykman --version`. I'm getting an error like,

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/ykman", line 6, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pkg_resources'
```

Please anyone help with this

Comment: Can' t reproduce on fresh 18.04 LTS VM. Please try to reinstall the involved packages by `sudo apt-get install --reinstall python3-pkg-resources yubikey-manager` and retry. Also please share the output of `which ykman; apt-cache policy python3-pkg-resources yubikey-manager; which python; which python3` .

Comment: Thanks! Mine was solved with a simple `$ apt install python3-pkg-resources`. Turns out `$ apt install yubikey-manager` doesn't pull it. Reproduces with a fresh `$ docker run --rm -it ubuntu bash` and `$ apt install yubikey-manager && ykman`

Comment: Adding the PPA solved it after trying all your commands without success. Added PPA and ran --reinstall command